# Is there a max array size limitation for the opencv resize function?

Tags: python, opencv, resize

I am working on object detection in images and am using a vectorized array of image slices from a sliding window on the main image. I would like to resize all the windows to a small size for passing to the object detector. Unfortunately I find that when I use the opencv resize function it is only able to resize a small chunk of the images I pass to it at once before it stops working.

In the final lines of the code below there are two lines specifying the number of windows to try to resize at once. For the given window size it works with 512 and fails with 513 windows. If there is a max array size limitation in the resize function that would be a difference between 3481600 and 3488400 array values.

I haven't been able to find anything in the opencv documentation referencing a size limitation for the resize function, but has anyone run into this problem?

Are there other resize functions in different modules that are known to have larger capacities for vectorized image slice shrinking?

My current work around has been to loop over the array of images resizing them in chunks smaller than my experimentally determined max array size.

Any advice/wisdom is appreciated!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('best_of_hope_kolosser_water_snow.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


## ---- these would normally be function arguments for this module -------
window_size = np.resize(np.array([int(100/1.45),100]),(1,2))
w = 0
strX_wPerc = 1/6
strY_wPerc = 1/6
data_patch_size = (30,46)
## ---- end of; locally defining function arguments for module --------

## ---- sliding window params -----  
win_w = window_size[w,0]  
win_h = window_size[w,1]  
strideX = int(window_size[w,0]*strX_wPerc)
strideY = int(window_size[w,1]*strY_wPerc)
## ----------------------------------

print('img shape: ', img.shape)
# ^^ prints: img shape:  (1200, 1920)

## -------- sliding window vectorization steps --------------------------
num_vert_windows = len(np.arange(0,img.shape[0]-window_size[w,1],strideY)) # number of vertical windows that will be created
indx = np.arange(0,img.shape[0]-window_size[w,1],strideY)[:,None]+np.arange(window_size[w,1]) # index that will be broadcasted across image
vertical_windows = img[indx] # array of windows win_h tall and the full width of the image

vertical_windows = np.transpose(vertical_windows,(0,2,1)) # transpose to prep for broadcasting
num_horz_windows = len(np.arange(0,vertical_windows.shape[1]-window_size[w,0],strideX)) # number of horizontal windows that will be created
indx = np.arange(0,vertical_windows.shape[1]-window_size[w,0],strideX)[:,None]+np.arange(window_size[w,0]) # index for broadcasting across vertical windows
all_windows = vertical_windows[0:vertical_windows.shape[0],indx] # array of all the windows
## -------- end of, sliding window vectorization ------------------------

total_windows = num_vert_windows*num_horz_windows
all_windows = np.transpose(all_windows,(3,2,1,0)) # rearrange for resizing and intuitive indexing
all_windows = np.resize(all_windows,(window_size[w,1],window_size[w,0],total_windows)) # resize to stack all windows

print('sliding windows height:',all_windows.shape[0],', width:',all_windows.shape[1],', number of windows:',all_windows.shape[2])
# ^^ prints: sliding windows height: 100 , width: 68 , number of windows: 11661

##num_windows_to_resize = all_windows.shape[2] # ideally this would resize them all at once
num_windows_to_resize = 512 # 513 fails
small_windows = cv2.resize(all_windows[:,:,0:num_windows_to_resize],data_patch_size,0,0,cv2.INTER_AREA) 

print('final windows (height, width, # windows):',small_windows.shape)
# ^^ if resizing less than 513 windows, prints: final windows (height, width, # windows): (46, 30, 512)
# ^^ if resizing more than 512 windows, prints: final windows (height, width, # windows): (46, 30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, what you are asking can be summed into the following

```py
>>> cv2.resize(np.zeros([1200,1920,512]), (30,46)).shape
(46,30,512)
>>> cv2.resize(np.zeros([1200,1920,513]), (30,46)).shape
(46,30)
```

So why does the first line resizes all channels, while the second line seems to result in only 1 channel?

I found that by default OpenCV does not support more than 512 channels in a single image. As defined in `cvdef.h`

```
#define CV_CN_MAX     512
```

So what happens is that the input of `cv2.resize` is reduced to only the first channel. Changing the maximum channels is not recommended either as discussed here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/46296/increase-the-maximum-amount-of-channels-in-cvmat/ 
So unfortunately that means you will have to resize in batches.

Comment: Thanks iamai that explains the problem. I'll probably look for another route for shrinking those slices in a non-image specific package since I didn't realize opencv was interpreting my index input as color channels. 

Also thanks for boiling my question down so clearly. Should I edit my question so it only contains the important part that you stated, or just leave it as is?